# Default Interceptors in CDI Beans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, java-melody

I have a question. Whenever we have EJB jars

```
<ejb-jar
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   version = "3.0"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd"
        >
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor>
            <interceptor-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringInterceptor</interceptor-class>
        </interceptor>
    </interceptors>
    <assembly-descriptor>
        <interceptor-binding>
            <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
            <interceptor-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringInterceptor</interceptor-class>
        </interceptor-binding>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```

Now my *MonitoringInterceptor* Intercept all EJBs. Here comes a question: can I do something similar with CDI Interceptors?

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    <interceptors>
        <class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>

</beans>
```

I would like to have *MonitoringInterceptor* set by default to all CDI Beans injected to application. How can I acquire that?

Comment: I don't think there is a declarative way to do it - with good reason as "all beans" is a rather vague concept in the world of CDI. Beans come and go even after deployment time. This article describes a way to do it programmatically for all beans which are registered with the manager, which will possibly net you your desired result: http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-add-cdi-interceptor-programmatically . Untested and nothing of my own in here, so I'll have to leave it as a comment.

Comment: Perfect soultion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a declarative way to do it - with good reason as "all beans" is a rather vague concept in the world of CDI. Beans come and go even after deployment time. This article describes a way to do it programmatically for all beans which are registered with the manager, which will possibly net you your desired result: [byteslounge.com/tutorials/…](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-add-cdi-interceptor-programmatically)

Comment: I posted the comment as answer, to avoid it to be listed as unanswered

Comment: I found this article two years ago and resolved my problem :) I think it's valid answer

Comment: (I know this is old; just wanted to correct something.) Beans in CDI do not "come and go". A bean is a factory of contextual instances. CDI beans are immutable after the container starts up. That is one of CDI's strengths.

Answer (score 0):

A way would be to create an Extension that adds the Annotation to the classes.

As practical example you can look at
[EjbExtensionExtended](https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit/blob/master/modules/ioc-unit-ejb/src/main/java/com/oneandone/iocunit/ejb/EjbExtensionExtended.java)

```
processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T> pat)
```

makes sure that the beans can be handled

```
createEJBWrapper
```

adds @EjbTransactional to the class if necessary.